# Groovy list of map custom sorting by other list order

Tags: groovy

I have a list of map like below:

```
List listOfMap = [
            [
                "id": 20914,
                "objectProp": "document.forms[0].elements[9]",
                "locator": "dom"
            ],
            [
                "id": 20916,
                "objectProp": "//tr[5]/td[2]/select",
                "locator": "xpath"
            ], 
            [
                "id": 20917,
                "locator": "label",
                "objectProp": "Title"
            ], 
            [
                "id": 20919,
                "objectProp": "document.forms[0].elements['pt1:USma:0:MAnt1:1:pt1:pt_r1:0:AP1:NewPe1:0:pt_r1:0:r1:0:i1:6:selectOneChoice4']",
                "locator": "dom"
            ]
        ]
```

I want to `sort` above `listOfMap` by using below locator's list order :

```
List locatorPosition = ["id", "name", "tagName", "className", "linkText", "partialLinkText", "label", "cssSelector", "xpath", "dom"]
```

Desire output like below:

```
[[id:20917, locator:label, objectProp:Title], [id:20916, objectProp://tr[5]/td[2]/select, locator:xpath], [id:20914, objectProp:document.forms[0].elements[9], locator:dom], [id:20919, objectProp:document.forms[0].elements['pt1:USma:0:MAnt1:1:pt1:pt_r1:0:AP1:NewPe1:0:pt_r1:0:r1:0:i1:6:selectOneChoice4'], locator:dom]]
```

Have you all any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List listOfMap = [
            [
                "id": 20914,
                "objectProp": "document.forms[0].elements[9]",
                "locator": "dom"
            ],
            [
                "id": 20916,
                "objectProp": "//tr[5]/td[2]/select",
                "locator": "xpath"
            ], 
            [
                "id": 20917,
                "locator": "label",
                "objectProp": "Title"
            ], 
            [
                "id": 20919,
                "objectProp": "document.forms[0].elements['pt1:USma:0:MAnt1:1:pt1:pt_r1:0:AP1:NewPe1:0:pt_r1:0:r1:0:i1:6:selectOneChoice4']",
                "locator": "dom"
            ]
        ]

def order = ["id", "name", "tagName", "className", "linkText", "partialLinkText", "label", "cssSelector", "xpath", "dom"]
def sorted = listOfMap.sort { order.indexOf(it.locator) }
assert sorted.locator == ['label', 'xpath', 'dom', 'dom']
```

Comment: what should I for this `ListOfMap = [
                [
                    "id": 20624,
                    "objectProp": "#userid",
                    "locator": "cssselector"
                ],
                [
                    "id": 20628,
                    "objectProp": "//input[1]",
                    "locator": "xpath"
                ],
                [
                    "id": 20631,
                    "locator": "id",
                    "objectProp": "userid"
                ]
            ]`

Comment: It's fail for this list

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, what is failing?

Comment: failing due to case.. But I got it by this way ...`listOfMap.sort { locatorPosition*.toLowerCase().indexOf(it.locator.toLowerCase()) }`